# converting object{double[,]} to double[,] or int[,] in C#.net

Tags: c#, matlab, object

i am using a MATLAB dll. it takes a matrix as type int[,] as input and the output is as type :object{double[,]}

```
 private void pic_edges(int[,] array)
    {

        Class1  obj = new Class1();
        object res = null;
        res = obj.edge_dll(1, array, .5);
     }
```

name    ;             value           ;       type

res       ;           {object[1]}      ;     object{object[]}
 [0]   ;                {double[450,600]}   ;  object{double[,]}

now i want to change object{double[,]}  to int[,]  or double[,].  but how???

```
int[,] pic=null;
double[,] pic2=nu1l;
```

edit :

i used the following code :(thanks to 'now he who must not be named')

```
 var objectArray = obj.edge_dll(1, array, .5);
  double[,] pic3 = (double[,]) objectArray[0];
```

and it converts correctly.
Now how to convert double[,]  to  int [,]

i used this code : (But is there any better way??)

```
int[,] pic4 =new int[pic3.GetLength(0),pic3.GetLength(1)];
        for (var i = 0; i < pic3.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < pic3.GetLength(1); j++)
                pic4[i, j] = (int)pic3[i, j];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `type-cast` it.

If i understand your question correctly, you have something to convert from an object to integer array.

Try something like this:

```
        var objectArray  = obj.edge_dll(1, array, .5);

        for (var index = 0; index <= objectArray.Count(); index++)
        {
            anIntegerArray[index] = (int) objectArray[index];
        }
```

Comment: it says :  Cannot unbox 'objectArray[0]' as a 'int'

Comment: That means that objectArray[0] is not an integer. Can you tell us exactly the signature of the method obj.edge_dll()? What does it return? [If its returning an object array the above should have worked.] So, you are missing out something

Comment: does it return a key-value pair or some thing like, object[value1, value2] ?

Comment: thanks for your help. in my post i have shown the type and value of output [res]..  now most of the problem is solved. now i want to convert double[,]  to  int[,].